# In SSIS, can we download data from a server which only supports Active Directory Integrated Authentication

Tags: ssis, active-directory

Using SSIS, we need to download data from a server  which only supports Active Directory Integrated Authentication. Is it possible? What is the process?

Comment: Could you give more information on this, to help determine which part of this is a problem you'd like to fix. Answer without this information: You could make sure the SSIS job is running under an Active Directory account that the server knows has permissions. Or you could have a job on that server that puts the data in a place that your SSIS job can reach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  The process is to use a connection string that specifies integrated security, and to run the package in the context of an active directory user account that has the needed permission on the database server.

Answer (score 0):

Got this. Updated Data Tools to Sql Server Data Tools Update 2 and using ado.net connection, I am able to pull data from the server.